# My commitment token from the UI site hasn't been returned

Tags: support, status-completed, area-51

Is returning the commitment token from a site a manual process or is it automatic?

If it's automatic what are the criteria? I've made 14 posts (2 questions and 12 answers), commented and earned 11 badges including the beta.

I'm not concerned as I still have one token left and there's nothing I really want to commit to at the moment. It's just that it was discussed on chat yesterday and someone mentioned that they'd had their token from the Unix site returned and that went into beta *after* the UI site.

Comment: Same here... I want my UI commitment complete too.

Comment: I guess there are quite a few that want the token back myself included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed now.

Commitment tokens are supposed to be returned automatically, but we had a bug in which Area 51 was failing to take account for the Beta badge having a different Id in the newer sites (16) than in the older sites (30).

Comment: Isn't that going to cause problems in the future - badges having different IDs?